# How is the Ruby Load Path set? The "$:" global

Tags: ruby, load

When I set the load path on command line using -I, is it ALWAYS the case that this path is the first item in the $: array?

Is it ever possible that this path is NOT the first item in the $: array?

Comment: Not sure, but it's a pretty safe bet that if you shift your path at the top of your script, that it's going to be the first. Unless you're code does more shifting later.

Answer (score 2):

That mostly depends on version of Ruby interpreter/virtual machine you're using, but, generally, that's the purpose of `-I` option: you should be able to override default `$LOAD_PATH` with it.

If you want to supply `$LOAD_PATH` components using command-line that would be applied in other position, you're free to implement your own command-line options, such as

```
require 'getoptlong'

opts = GetoptLong.new(['--include', '-I', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT ])

opts.each { |opt, arg|
  $LOAD_PATH << arg if opt == '--include'
}
```

Comment: do you have any info on how portable that statement is?

Comment: It depends on how you define "portable". Both using `-I` in command line of Ruby interpreter/virtual machine and using some other command-line option from application itself (as done in this example) is portable across operating systems and various Ruby versions. The behavior of `$LOAD_PATH` is well-defined. However I suspect that some versions (or platforms) might lack command-line (for example, I'm not sure that you can start a program with command-line arguments on Android platform or in S60 port).